# Taking control of a program another user started in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, process

The company I work for is adding securities per user. We used to use generic log-ins so that multiple people could use a single machine with out restarting our programs. The program takes 2-4 minutes to load depending on computer specs and internet speed. This wasn't a Problem if it only needed to be open once a day.

Now it has become a hassle for all the users as they have their own unique log-ins and have to close the program when they leave the computer. Then the next user that comes along has to reopen it wasting 2-4 minutes each switch. The program also has issues if it is open multiple times on any one machine.

These are all Windows 7 Pro 32bit or 64bit machines.

I was wondering/hoping there would be a way to "hijack" a process, processes, applications from one user to the current user. Or if there was a way to allow a program to be more global so if it is open it is open across all users.

Secondary, if this is not possible I would need to find a way to only allow one instance of the program to exist on 1 machine.

Thank you for your help!

Addition:
I am an IT guy for the company, I did not know super user was specifically for "personal and home computer networking" when I cam here I only saw "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users". I apologize, sorry.  Our increased security is to become PCI compliant. Our cashier are having to close our POS system and log off windows each shift change or break they take. This is causing our customer to have to wait 2-4 minutes in line just for our POS to load.

I'm trying to find a way around the reloading of our POS system by pulling it from one Cashier's Log-in to another Cashier's log-in. So that the only loading is windows loading the user's profile.

One way I had thought about was perhaps a remote desktop scenario where the check-stand computer is not the computer actually running the program. This would allow multiple users to access it but only one use it at any given time. But this has it's own sets of vulnerabilities.

Another thought was a shared VM that we can pause and save in a shared folder and load back up when the next user came along.

I was hoping there were some commands I could throw in a .bat, no monkey business. They would just have to run the batch file which would change the process and application user.

If this question does not belong here, please recommend a place to take it to. I <3 StackExchange

Comment: Superuser is only for "personal and home computer networking". **NOT** for helping you circumvent your company's security. You need to contact your company's IT department.

Comment: You're putting too much emphasis on the questioner's guess as to answers. Consider instead the question from this perspective: _We have some software that we used to run single-user just fine. We're now taking advantage of our multi-user operating system to give everyone their own individual accounts. But the software breaks. Is there any compatibility/virtualization/whatever mechanism in Windows that we can use to enable multiple users to run the software happily? The setup/teardown costs of exiting/restarting the program just to switch user are very high._  Compatibility, not cracking.

Comment: CharlieRB, You could have stopped at "personal and home computer networking". I am one of the 3 IT guys for this company. I will go somewhere else to get this answered. I just figured this would be interesting knowledge for anyone to have. Not just me as an IT guy but also for personal use. If you don't know how to help, why comment?

JdeBP, thank you for your understanding and rephrasing!

Comment: @dBaker just for future reference, Corporate IT level questions are supposed to go on http://serverfault.com. "Server Fault is a question and answer site for professional system and network administrators."

Comment: `Another thought was a shared VM `. That actually sound like an idea which can work. If you run the POS application on the VM and then remote desktop to it (or VNC, or X, or any other protocol which you are familiar with).